# multi css selectors not applying style

Tags: nativescript

I have a class that when clicked is styled differently.

I tried to have the element as:

```
<GridLayout (tap)="onHeaderClicked()" cssClass="table-header" [class.open]="isOpen"> </GridLayout>
```

however when trying to apply styling to:

```
.table-header.open{

}
```

the css is not getting applied, I have now had to resort to the following syntax and have 2 methods:

```
<GridLayout (tap)="onHeaderClicked()"  cssClass="{{isOpen ? 'table-header-open' : 'table-header-closed' }}">
```

and create styles for these individually

is this possible in nativescript?

Comment: Check if the classes are actually added to the elements using browser devtools. Where are you adding the styles?

Comment: this is compiled into an android app and im unable to inspect the classes at runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want to add specific style on runtime, you could use ViewChild decorator and with its help to create new property, which is pointing to the GridLayout. With this property you could change existing style properties to this element.

app.component.html

```
<GridLayout #container (tap)="onHeaderClicked()" rows="auto" columns="auto" width="200" height="300" cssClass="{{isOpen ? 'table-header-open' : 'table-header-closed'}}">
    <Label row="0" col="0" text="sample text" textWrap="true"></Label> 
</GridLayout>
```

app.component.ts

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef} from "@angular/core"; 
import {setTimeout} from "timer"; 
import {View} from "ui/core/view"; 
import {GridLayout} from "ui/layouts/grid-layout"; 
import {Color} from "color"

@Component({
    selector: "my-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html",
})
export class AppComponent {
    public isOpen:boolean;


    @ViewChild("container") container: ElementRef;

    constructor(){
        this.isOpen = true;
        var that = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            that.isOpen=false;
        },3000);


    }
    public onHeaderClicked()
    {
        let container = <GridLayout>this.container.nativeElement;
        container.color=new Color("blue");
    }
}
```

app.css

```
.table-header-open{
    background-color: red;
}

.table-header-closed{
    background-color: green;
}
```